# Generic Type Casting compile check error

Tags: swift, casting, generic-programming

Here is my code

```
func testFuncA<T>(_ value: T) {
    if let rValue = value as? Encodable {
        testFuncB(rValue)//error in here: Cannot invoke 'testFuncB' with an argument list of type '(Encodable)'
    }
}

func testFuncB<T: Encodable>(_ value: T)  {

}
```

why can not invoke`testFuncB`? is `T` can cast to `T: Encodable` ?

Comment: Protocols don't conform to themselves; `Encodable` is not a type that conforms to `Encodable`, therefore you cannot use it to satisfy the type variable `T` where `T : Encodable`.

Comment: Is there no way to invoke `testFuncB` with `value`?

Comment: You could use a type-erasing `AnyEncodable` wrapper (such as shown in the linked Q&A) which you could then pass to `testFuncB`, although you wouldn't be able to do the same for decoding (you need a concrete type to decode into).

Comment: Your comment is very usefull, but if `testFuncB` is an Apple API such as `JSONEncoder`'s `func encode<T>(_ value: T) throws -> Data where T : Encodable`,  it's also can not invoke

Comment: Not sure I follow you; [works fine for me](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/581647517cca4e2d2991db81247f7fa5).

Comment: Oh，I go the wrong way, lost to comform`Encodable`，Thank you very much!